# View Filter Criteria - And/Or conditions for group filters- Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

The filter criteria And/Or condition looks as below:

In the filter below, I want to change the highlighted 'AND' as 'OR' criteria. But changing that does not have any impact on the view query.

[image]

The query looks as below:

```
WHERE 
([node_field_data].[status] = @P10)
AND ([node_field_data].[type] IN (@P11) 
AND ([node__field_zip].[field_zip_value] LIKE @P12) 
OR ([node__field_miles].[field_miles_value] LIKE @P13))
```

I want to change the highlighted 'AND' condition to 'OR' condition. But changing that does not have any impact on the filter criteria. It switches back to 'AND'. I want the resultant query as below:

```
WHERE 
([node_field_data].[status] = @P10)
AND ([node_field_data].[type] IN (@P11) 
OR ([node__field_zip].[field_zip_value] LIKE @P12) 
OR ([node__field_miles].[field_miles_value] LIKE @P13))
```

Any help on how this can be fixed? Thanks!

Comment: The first 3 OR are not doing anything. The should be nested together in one.